# GET Method - passing parameter with two variables - submit button

Tags: html, forms, methods, get

Having a bit of trouble with a form. Is any one who know's the ins and outs of GET able to have a look at this markup and suggest what is going wrong?

I have already looked into it and came across this answer: [How can I pass a parameter via submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797285/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-via-submit-button/21002424#21002424) - scripting is taken from there but am still unsure where I am going wrong. The url is being populated but no value is being passed into it, so this is what I get: 'gender='

**Markup:**

```
<form onsubmit="validateEmail(document.emailsonly1,'Please enter a valid email address'); return false;" method="get" action="http://URL" name="emailsonly1">
<input type="hidden" name="gender">
<input type="image" src="/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/spacer.gif" class="buttonSignUpGirl" id="btnSignUpGirl" onclick="setType('1')">
<input type="image" src "/content/ebiz/shop/resources/images/spacer.gif" class="buttonSignUpBoy" id="btnSignUpBoy" onclick="setType('2')">
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
function setType(type)
{
document.getElementById('gender').value = type;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a new function for that, just do

```
<form onsubmit="validateEmail(...); return false;" method="get" action="http://URL" name="emailsonly1">
<input type="hidden" name="gender">
<input type="image" src="your image" onclick="emailsonly1['gender'].value = 1;">
<input type="image" src "your image" onclick="emailsonly1['gender'].value = 2;">
</form>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdmartin/sX84L/)

BTW, it was probably not working because you forgot to give an id to the gender field.

Comment: Working perfectly! I'll keep it simple and use this. Many thanks @tdmartin